# jQueryMobile - Fixed header changes size if input is selectet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am currently experiencing a weird issue with a fixed header. As soon as I focus on a input-field it gets bigger and actually "grows" over the input-field itself. Every time I focus another input-field it just grows bigger (E.g. the padding of the parent div grows)

Here is the HTML-Markup I am using

```
 <!-- Settings !-->
    <section id="settings" data-role="page" data-pagination="4" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="a">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Every time I focus my input-field the class "ui-fixed-header" gets added to the header itself. Removing it with jQuery does not bring the expected effect. Did everybody experience a similar effect and how did you solve it?

Comment: What version of jQM are you using?  Where are the inputs? can you make this happen in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi, I am using jQuery 2.0.3 and jQM 1.3.2 . I have prepared a fiddle, that looks similar to my setup, but as life plays I can't reproduce the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/8q57X/ . It seems that for some reason in my script the padding-top of my jqm-page gets increased by 200 pixels

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by overwriting certain css-values, that get changed if a input is selected. Here is how it worked for me:

```
.ui-fixed-hidden{
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui-header-fixed{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: -1px !important;
    padding-top: 1px !important;
}

.ui-header{
    position: fixed !important;
}
```